# How to add Dummy content when active wordpress theme without xml import?

Tags: theme-development

Actually i am creating a theme using option tree plugin and now i want i just copy the theme folder and paste it into another WordPress setup and  then whole dummy content should automatically populated.

Answer (score -1):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/fakerpress/ plugin should solve your problem. It populates entire blog with configurable dummy content.

Comment: No I not want to use any plugin

Comment: Doesn't make sense to require installing a plugin before installing a theme

Comment: Plenty of templates ship with required plugins, but as you like